# How to get/remove string and the char before from object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

So i have this object of photos, which is value of some hidden input:

`53bd570ba13ef.jpg,53bd570c964c3.jpg,53bd570d311c9.jpg,53bd570db8997.jpg`.

What i need is to remove last string witch number and the comma before: `,53bd570db8997.jpg`.

```
var dataInput = $('#images'),
    imgs = dataInput.val(),
    thumbIndex = $(this).parent().index();
//
var _result = imgs.split(',')[thumbIndex];
//
var name = _result.slice(0, _result.indexOf(","));

console.log(name);
```

The thumbIndex is my photo number/name without the comma: `53bd570db8997.jpg`. Can anybody help?

Comment: you want to get ``53bd570db8997.jpg`` from the string?

Comment: i need the number with the comma

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, I'd regexp it:

```
imgs.replace(new RegExp("," + thumbIndex),"");
```

imgs should be the string you posted above (the comma-separated one).

Comment: thumbIndex is an integer and represented as index, it is not a text

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that thumbIndex contains the last filename, you can get away with this:

```
var data = '53bd570ba13ef.jpg,53bd570c964c3.jpg,53bd570d311c9.jpg,53bd570db8997.jpg'; // or $('#images').val()
var thumbIndex = '53bd570db8997.jpg';

var result = data.substr(0, data.indexOf(thumbIndex) - 1);
```

Comment: in thumbIndex i have the number of photo after the comma, so it's 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could elaborate a little bit more on what precisely you want to achieve, but I'm going to make an attempt at understanding your question and I will try to give you a solution.

As I understand, you wish to get the last element from a string of values which are delimited by a ',' character.

You could of course split the string and simply get the last element from the array.

```
var dataInput = $('#images');
var imgs      = dataInput.val();
var _result   = imgs.split(',');
var thumbnail = _result[_result.length - 1];

console.log(thumbnail);
```

Here's a JSFiddle to try out: http://jsfiddle.net/WBb5F/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you can try [lastIndexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp)

```
var result = data.substr(0, data.indexOf(','));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSgqX/)

Answer (score -1):

Using this html

```
<input type="hidden" value="53bd570ba13ef.jpg,53bd570c964c3.jpg,53bd570d311c9.jpg,53bd570db8997.jpg" id="images" />
```

To get the last item you can do this:

```
var dataInput = $('#images'),
    imgs = dataInput.val(),
    thumbIndex = imgs.split(',').length;
var name = imgs.split(',')[thumbIndex - 1]
console.log(','+ name);
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SamMonk/zHLLJ/)

Comment: i need fe. the last number with the comma